# Error for picasso for "method with.this()"

Tags: android, picasso

I am trying to add an image when getting json array object.

The error is  `with.(this)` method for this line of code:

```
Picasso.with(this)
  .load("urlpicture"+JO.get("post_img_url"))
  .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
  .resize(200,200);
```

What should i put into this method? here is the code. What should i put in `Picasso.with()` method?

```
package com.example.json3;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import static com.example.json3.R.drawable.*;


public class fetchData extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {
    String data ="";
    String dataParsed = "";
    String singleParsed ="";

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL("website for json url");
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String line = "";
            while(line != null){
                line = bufferedReader.readLine();
                data = data + line;
            }

            JSONArray JA = (JSONArray) new JSONObject(data).get("posts");

            for(int i =0 ;i <JA.length(); i++)
            {

                JSONObject JO = (JSONObject) JA.get(i);
                singleParsed =  "title:" + JO.get("title").toString() + "\n"+
                        "author:" + JO.get("author").toString() + "\n"+
                "description:" + JO.get("description").toString() + "\n"+
                "post_img_url:" + JO.get("post_img_url").toString() + "\n";



               //int image =  ic_launcher_foreground;
                Picasso.with(this).load("urlpicture"+JO.get("post_img_url")).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background).resize(200,200);
                dataParsed = dataParsed + singleParsed +"\n" ;
            }




        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

        MainActivity.data.setText(this.dataParsed);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the context of the activity and fetchData is not an activity here. You can do something like this to get activity context.

```
        public class fetchData extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {
        String data ="";
        String dataParsed = "";
        String singleParsed ="";
        Context context;

        public fetchData(Context context){
            this.context=context;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL("website for json url");
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                String line = "";
                while(line != null){
                    line = bufferedReader.readLine();
                    data = data + line;
                }

                JSONArray JA = (JSONArray) new JSONObject(data).get("posts");

                for(int i =0 ;i <JA.length(); i++)
                {

                    JSONObject JO = (JSONObject) JA.get(i);
                    singleParsed =  "title:" + JO.get("title").toString() + "\n"+
                            "author:" + JO.get("author").toString() + "\n"+
                            "description:" + JO.get("description").toString() + "\n"+
                            "post_img_url:" + JO.get("post_img_url").toString() + "\n";



                    //int image =  ic_launcher_foreground;
                    Picasso.with(context).load("urlpicture"+JO.get("post_img_url")).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background).resize(200,200);
                    dataParsed = dataParsed + singleParsed +"\n" ;
                }




            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

            MainActivity.data.setText(this.dataParsed);

        }
    }
```

And in your activity

```
new fetchData(this);
```